# How do I call onto a separate header.php?

Tags: php, wordpress

To be honest I do not understand PHP just yet. But what I am trying to achieve sounds easy in my head.

Here is the code at the top of my wordpress `single.php` file:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

I have created a separate header i.e `header2.php`.

I want to know what do I need to write at the top of my `single.php` template to call `header2.php` instead of `header.php`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to have header-2.php (and not header2.php) you have to call:

```
<?php get_header('2'); ?>
```

See this page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header

Answer (score 3):

Just create a header file like

```
header-myHeader2.php
```

and call it like

```
get_header('myHeader2');
```

Syntax is `header-name.php` and you can call using the `name` part.

[Read more here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header).